Loop lifts uniquely to another loop
Question:
Let $B$ be a space with fundamental group $\pi_{1}(B, b)$, and let $E$ be a covering space of $B$ with covering map $p$. Let $f$ be a loop at $b$ with $[f]$ the identity in $\pi_{1}(B, b)$.
Prove that the unique lifting $\tilde{f}$ of $f$ starting at any $e \in p^{-1}(\{b\})$ must also be a loop and that $\tilde{[f]}$ is also the identity element of $\pi_{1}(E, e)$.
I already proved the second statement under the assumption that the first statement is true. However I am struggling with proving the first statement, that is, proving that $\tilde{f}$ must be a loop in $E$. I tried to argue that $p^{-1}(b)$ contains a single element but I failed to do so. If anyone has a hint I would appreciate that.

Try lifting a homotopy.

Thank you for your comment @BenSteffan. I was wondering if the following approach is correct: since $[f]$ is the identity in $\pi_{1}(B, b)$, $f$ is path-homotopic to the constant path $e_{b}$ based at $b$. Let $H$ be this path-homotopy. Then $H$ uniquely lifts to a path-homotopy $\tilde{H}$ between the liftings $\tilde{f}$ and $\tilde{e_{b}}$. Now these have the same starting/ending points and are path-homotopic. Since $\tilde{e_{b}}$ is the constant path with base-point $e$, $\tilde{f}$ must be a loop based at $e$. Now $[\tilde{f}]$ is the identity since $\tilde{f} \simeq_{p} \tilde{e_{b}}$.

Yes, that's it :)
